# Can we convert data frame in Databricks to string and why do we get error Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm selecting a column that's a data frame. I would like to cast it as a string so that it can be used to frame cosmos DB dynamic query. The function collect() on data frame complains about queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;

```
val DF = AppointmentDF
            .select("*")
            .filter($"xyz" === "abc")

DF.createOrReplaceTempView("MyTable")
val column1DF = spark.sql("SELECT column1 FROM MyTable")


// This is not getting resolved
val sql="select c.abc from c where c.column = \"" + String.valueOf(column1DF) + "\""
println(sql)

Error:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`column1DF`' given input columns: []; line 1 pos 12;


DF.collect().foreach { row =>
  println(row.mkString(","))
 } 

 Error: 
 org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must 
 be executed with writeStream.start();;
```

Answer (score 1):

A dataframe is a distributed data structure, not a structure located in your machine that can be printed. The value `DF` and `column1DF` are going to be exactly dataframes. To bring all the data of your queries, to the driver node, you can use the dataframe method [collect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@collect():Array[T]), and extract from the returning Array of rows your value.
Collect can be harmful if you are bringing gigabytes of data to the memory of your driver node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collect` and take `head` for getting first line of `DataFrame`:

```
val column1DF = spark.sql("SELECT column1 FROM MyTable").collect().head.getAs[String](0)
val sql="select c.abc from c where c.column = \"" + column1DF + "\""
```

Comment: I am in scala notebook command and get this. 'Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;'